# excluding yaml file (models) or a package from the openApi generator process

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, openapi, openapi-generator

I successfully did generate Rest Api controllers and models using openApi-generator-maven plugin version 4.2.3.
in the yaml contract, we reference and external YAML file that contains shared models :

```
schema:
  $ref : 'mycontract.yaml#/components/schemas/PrjExceptionHandler'
```

this shared yaml is under a specific package. Is there a way to ignore the yaml file (the models defined inside this yaml) from the generation process?
actually, I m using .openapi-generator-ignore file to ignore the models one by one
Ex:

```
**/PrjExceptionHandler*
```

I m looking for a global solution where I can ignore all the models of a given Yaml file or package to be ignored, Also by doing the actual solution im getting a compilation error at the generation process where the objects a complaining about *PrjExceptionHandler* to not be defined.

thank you for your support.